# Slow matrix multiplication when using OpenCL enabled OpenCV

Tags: c++, performance, opencv, opencl

I made a simple program to test the performance of OpenCV with and without the help of GPU. GPU code is implemented using OpenCV/OpenCL Transparent API method.

Overall, GPU enabled process always runs faster than CPU except for **matrix multiplication** which is surprising considering multiplication process is bread and butter for a good GPU performance.

Here are the code used to run my simple test:

```
     #include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
    #include <opencv2\opencv_modules.hpp>
    #include <opencv2\core\ocl.hpp>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>

    // Here are the functions used to measure time
    double m_dTime = 0;

    void perfMeasure_start()
    {
        m_dTime = cv::getTickCount();
    }

    void perfMeasure_end(std::string strLabel)
    {
        double currentTime = cv::getTickCount();
        double dTimeTaken = (currentTime - m_dTime) / cv::getTickFrequency();
        printf("[TIME]%25s : %.3lf ms\n", strLabel.c_str(), dTimeTaken * 1000);
        m_dTime = currentTime;
     }

    void OpenCLProc(cv::InputArray matSrc, cv::OutputArray matDst)
    {
        perfMeasure_start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            cv::cvtColor(matSrc, matDst, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        }
        perfMeasure_end("cvtColor");

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            cv::GaussianBlur(matDst, matDst, cv::Size(9, 9), 1.5);
        }
        perfMeasure_end("GaussianBlur");

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            cv::Canny(matDst, matDst, 0, 50);
        }
        perfMeasure_end("Canny");

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            cv::dilate(matDst, matDst, cv::noArray());
        }
        perfMeasure_end("Dilate");

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            cv::add(matSrc, matSrc, matDst);
        }
        perfMeasure_end("Add");

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            cv::multiply(matSrc, matDst, matDst);
        }
        perfMeasure_end("multiply");

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            cv::multiply(matSrc, 2.5, matDst);
        }
        perfMeasure_end("multiply_scalar");

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            cv::divide(matSrc, matDst, matDst);
        }
        perfMeasure_end("divide");

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            cv::divide(matSrc, 2.5, matDst);
        }
        perfMeasure_end("divide_Scalar");

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            cv::addWeighted(matSrc,2.5 ,matDst,0.6 ,0,matDst);
        }
        perfMeasure_end("addWeighted");

    }

    void TestOpenCL(cv::InputArray matSrc)
    {
        printf("[PERF] -= Performance Check =-\n");       
        printf("[PERF] ImageSize = %d x %d\n", matSrc.cols(), matSrc.rows());

        //////////// CPU MEASUREMENT CODE //////////////////////
        printf("[PERF] CPU Process\n");
        perfMeasure_start();
        cv::Mat img, gray;
        cv::Mat matImg, matDst;

        // Read
        matImg = matSrc.getMat();
        perfMeasure_end("Read");

        //Transfer
        matImg.copyTo(img);
        perfMeasure_end("Transfer CPU->CPU");

        // Process
        OpenCLProc(img, gray);

        // Transfer
        gray.copyTo(matDst);
        perfMeasure_end("Transfer CPU->CPU");

        std::cout << "\n";

        //////////////////// GPU MEASUREMENT CODE 1 //////////////////////
        printf("[PERF] GPU Process (copyTo)\n");
        cv::UMat img1, gray1;
        cv::Mat matImg1, matDst1;

        // Read
        matImg1 = matSrc.getMat();
        perfMeasure_end("Read");

        // Transfer
        matImg1.copyTo(img1);
        perfMeasure_end("Transfer CPU->GPU");

        //Process
        OpenCLProc(img1, gray1);

        // Transfer
        gray1.copyTo(matDst1);
        perfMeasure_end("Transfer GPU->CPU");
        std::cout << "\n";


        return;

    }


int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    if (argv[1] == "")
        std::cout << "Please insert image path" << std::endl;
    else {

        cv::Mat matSrc = cv::imread(argv[1]);

            // First round of process to let the GPU initialize
        TestOpenCL(matSrc);

            // The code performance is made based on result from this function
        TestOpenCL(matSrc);

    }


    return 0;
}
```

And here are the result which i plotted in bar chat.
Notice that GPU enabled processes always outperformed CPU implementation except for multiplication and weightedAdd function.

Is there a problem with the OpenCV function? How can multiplication function takes longer than division?

[image]

This process is run on

- Library : OpenCV3.3.1 build with OpenCL and TBB
- CPU     : Intel i7-6500U
- GPU     : Intel HD Graphics 520

Comment: similar for addWeighted according to your chart. Can you try cv::multiply(matSrc, matSrc, matDst); instead?

Comment: What size are matrices?

Comment: i am using a 4252 x 2835 color image